# Can "after trigger" be replaced completely by "instead of trigger"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I know basic trigger concepts and have played with it when I learn it. I don't have much practical experience on it, since I seldom use it. Now my question is, Can all **after trigger** be replaced completely by **instead of trigger**?

To me **instead of trigger** is kind of a "before trigger" and it fires before the action happens. So we can do something useful, or roll the transaction back. Since we can do anything, we can `INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE`. To me it seems like I can use **instead of trigger** to completely replace **after trigger**. Is that true?

Below is an example against SQL Server. The purpose of those two triggers are to prevent deletes. It seems both of them works.

```
USE test;
GO
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.a', N'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.a;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.a (id INT, c1 INT);
GO

INSERT  INTO a
VALUES  (1, 1);
GO

-- instead of trigger
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.t1', 'TR') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TRIGGER dbo.t1;
GO
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.t1 ON dbo.a
    INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK;
    PRINT 't1: Not allowed to delete data  from dbo.a';
END
GO


-- delete a row from the table to test the trigger
DELETE  FROM a
WHERE   id = 1;
-- and it works!

-- drop the first trigger
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.t1', 'TR') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TRIGGER dbo.t1;
GO

-- create an after trigger
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.t2', 'TR') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TRIGGER dbo.t2;
GO
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.t2 ON dbo.a
    AFTER DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK;
    PRINT 't2: Not allowed to delete data  from dbo.a';
END
GO


-- delete a row from the table to test the trigger
DELETE  FROM a
WHERE   id = 1;
-- and it works!


-- drop the second trigger
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.t2', 'TR') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TRIGGER dbo.t2;
GO
```

Comment: The answer is "yes", but you have to remember to do the action that you intend for the original statement to do.

Comment: IMHO,The answer is no.Its just you above example that justify that you should use "instead of trigger".But there can be other requirement where you have to use "AFTER DELETE".Say you want to insert the deleted in history table . Am I wrong @GordonLinoff ?

Comment: @KumarHarsh I think "insert the deleted in history table" is technically feasible with "instead of" trigger. In the trigger body we can first get the data that will be deleted from the pseudo table **deleted** and save them somewhere. Then we can delete those data simply by a **delete** statement by our-self.

Comment: I suspect much debugging of side-effects missing functionality. One reason I prefer AFTER myself is to ensure not messing with intended functionality. Would be a nasty surprised calling a delete to not have it delete things :)

Comment: Why the question?   There will be times when it's best to use AFTER, and times when it's best to use INSTEAD OF.   What use is it believing you know whether you can always use one to replace the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they can be made equivalent except you have to remember that in an after trigger the action has taken place - its up to you to undo it typically through a rollback.

In an instead of trigger the action has not taken place and its up to you (in the trigger) to do the action. An after trigger is often done as an audit step. An instead of is usually done to prevent something from happening.

The deleted and inserted tables are populated in either case.

You can step through the following code to verify what I just said:

drop table dbo.t1

create table dbo.t1  (i1 int)

insert into dbo.t1 values (1),(5), (6)

select * from dbo.t1

;
go

create trigger dbo.t2trig on dbo.t1
after delete AS

begin

```
select * from deleted

print 'in after trigger dbo.t1trig'
```

end

delete from dbo.t1 where i1 < 6

select * from dbo.t1

insert into dbo.t1 values (1),(5)

select * from dbo.t1

;
go

drop trigger dbo.t2trig

;
go

create trigger dbo.t2trig on dbo.t1
instead of delete AS

begin

```
select * from deleted

print 'in trigger instead of dbo.t1trig'
```

end

insert into dbo.t1 values (1),(5)

delete from dbo.t1 where i1 < 6

select * from dbo.t1